Load huge dataSet on UI from server as response object
I am try to load huge data (250 MB or 140000 records) from server to client(UI) as response. My server side process complete within only 90 secs. But when the output wrapper object is load from Server side to UI it taking 10 minutes something and during loading huge data as response on UI. UI is blocked completely.
I was think for apply pagination. But there problem is my API taking 90 seconds something to process data for Kpi evaluation and large dataset.
Please give me a solution for this.
The is response wrapper object which load on UI. inside datakey "info" it contain 140000 records like this.
Response Obj.
"{
"isTrend": false,
"headers": [
"1022-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME",
"1021-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME",
"1023-V 4G CSFB WCDMA",
"1024-S12 4G DL AVG ACTIVE USERS",
"1025-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME",
"1026-V 4G DL SCHEDULING TIME NUM",
"1027-V 4G DL PACKET LOSS RATE DENOM",
"1028-V 4G DL PACKET LOSS RATE NUM",
"1010-NSN 4G AVG RRC Connected Users",
"1033-S12 4G RRC SSR DENOM",
"1034-S12 4G RRC SSR NUM",
"1032-S12 4G ERAB INITIAL SSR NUM",
"1035-S12 4G S1 SSR DENOM",
"1036-S12 4G S1 SSR NUM",
"1037-S12 4G SERVICE DR DENOM",
"1038-S12 4G SERVICE DR NUM",
"1039-V 4G SESSION TIME UE",
"1041-S12 4G UL DATA VOLUME",
"1042-V 4G UL PACKET LOSS RATE DENOM",
"1043-V 4G UL PACKET LOSS RATE NUM"
],
"info": [
{
"neName": "UTTAR PRADESH",
"groupName": "1688238000000",
"valueMap": {
"1022-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME": "2.033054949332032E12",
"1021-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME": "2.033054949332032E12",
"1023-V 4G CSFB WCDMA": "2919116.0",
"1024-S12 4G DL AVG ACTIVE USERS": "0.7889",
"1025-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME": "2.033054949332032E12",
"1026-V 4G DL SCHEDULING TIME NUM": "1.8511616E7",
"1027-V 4G DL PACKET LOSS RATE DENOM": "2.59077293384E11",
"1028-V 4G DL PACKET LOSS RATE NUM": "6.2937388E7",
"1010-NSN 4G AVG RRC Connected Users": "5478916.0",
"1033-S12 4G RRC SSR DENOM": "4.54294264E8",
"1034-S12 4G RRC SSR NUM": "4.54086008E8",
"1032-S12 4G ERAB INITIAL SSR NUM": "7.58469064E8",
"1035-S12 4G S1 SSR DENOM": "4.99855076E8",
"1036-S12 4G S1 SSR NUM": "4.99571068E8",
"1037-S12 4G SERVICE DR DENOM": "7.57639136E8",
"1038-S12 4G SERVICE DR NUM": "5342016.0",
"1039-V 4G SESSION TIME UE": "306.7831",
"1041-S12 4G UL DATA VOLUME": "2.34380579043072E11",
"1042-V 4G UL PACKET LOSS RATE DENOM": "1.88993098652E11",
"1043-V 4G UL PACKET LOSS RATE NUM": "1.4096818E9"
}
},
{
"neName": "UTTAR PRADESH",
"groupName": "1688241600000",
"valueMap": {
"1022-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME": "2.033400510341728E12",
"1021-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME": "2.033400510341728E12",
"1023-V 4G CSFB WCDMA": "2919896.0",
"1024-S12 4G DL AVG ACTIVE USERS": "0.7885",
"1025-S12 4G DL DATA VOLUME": "2.033400510341728E12",
"1026-V 4G DL SCHEDULING TIME NUM": "1.850564E7",
"1027-V 4G DL PACKET LOSS RATE DENOM": "2.59096177868E11",
"1028-V 4G DL PACKET LOSS RATE NUM": "4.3750508E7",
"1010-NSN 4G AVG RRC Connected Users": "5479780.0",
"1033-S12 4G RRC SSR DENOM": "4.54393864E8",
"1034-S12 4G RRC SSR NUM": "4.54185572E8",
"1032-S12 4G ERAB INITIAL SSR NUM": "7.58619688E8",
"1035-S12 4G S1 SSR DENOM": "4.9995536E8",
"1036-S12 4G S1 SSR NUM": "4.9967134E8",
"1037-S12 4G SERVICE DR DENOM": "7.5778076E8",
"1038-S12 4G SERVICE DR NUM": "5342196.0",
"1039-V 4G SESSION TIME UE": "306.6988",
"1041-S12 4G UL DATA VOLUME": "2.34404720605344E11",
"1042-V 4G UL PACKET LOSS RATE DENOM": "1.88991062412E11",
"1043-V 4G UL PACKET LOSS RATE NUM": "1.391988056E9"
}
},
{...]}
